# CodeIgniter: Login in the main page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to have my login controller in my main page, but when I try to login it goes to a page with just the view/login code.
Here is my controller:

```
public function home(){
    $this->load->model("get_products");
    $data['results'] = $this->get_products->getData();

    $this->load->view("site_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");
    $this->load->view("content_home", $data);
    $this->load->view("content_left");
    $this->load->view("content_right");

    $this->login();
    $this->login_validation();

    $this->load->view("site_footer");
}

public function login(){
    $this->load->view('login');
}
public function login_validation(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5');

    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        $this->load->view('logged');
    } 

}
```

How can I login in the home page, without loading a new page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of 2 functions, use one function like this,

```
public function login(){

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $this->load->view('login'); 
    } else {
        // here you can redirect to main controller instead of loading the view, since ligin part is related here
        $this->load->view('logged');
    } 

}
```

And you are calling 2 functions in `home()`

```
$this->login();
$this->login_validation();
```

Both will not get called as you are loading a view in first one.

Comment: Ok now I'm able to login, but then it redirects me to the logged page, do you know how can I load the logged page in the home page?

Comment: which is home page controller?? in that load the required view.

Comment: If I redirect it to main the login stuff still appears. Instead of that I want the main controller to load but with the logged view, which displays a message like 'Welcome' and a logout button.

Comment: When I log in I want to display a message where the login credentials are, saying Welcome username. All the code is here except for the views

Comment: if login in success, store required values in session, use that in view to display that...